# use apt-get build essential with no internet

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, apt-get

I have a machine , a 64 ubuntu server Natty (11.04) 
I need to install a compiler (and basically do "apt-get build-essential" on it)
but I don't have a connection on it

I've so far tried using apt-offline ;it didn't work .
Can't use Keryx as I don't have a desktop of that server....
Can't use Synaptic either for the same reason
also tried downloading debian packages (gcc,g++,cpp,libc6,etc.)but the dependencies and configurations drove me nuts

any advice anyone?

Thanks

Comment: Download the full Ubuntu DVD and install from it via the package manager

Comment: Geoffrey, If I got you right,I don't have a desktop on the server on which I want to apt-get build-essential

Comment: Then insert the disk and run `apt-cdrom add` before running `apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: One more question, if the server is virtual, don't I need to use the iso image and mount it?

Comment: Yes, but that depends on the Virtualization package your using.

Comment: Ahh...it's kind of dynamic as I need to make an installer out of it..

Answer (score 0):

apt-offline was written for this very purpose. It has an option which covers the use case of **Build Dependencies**.

```
rrs@learner:~$ apt-offline set -h
usage: apt-offline set [-h] [--verbose] [--simulate]
                       [--install-packages [PKG [PKG ...]]]
                       [--install-src-packages [SOURCE PKG [SOURCE PKG ...]]]
                       [--src-build-dep] [--release release_name] [--update]
                       [--upgrade] [--upgrade-type upgrade]
                       [--generate-changelog] [--apt-backend apt-get]
                       apt-offline.sig

positional arguments:
  apt-offline.sig       Generate a signature file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --verbose             Enable verbose messages
  --simulate            Just simulate. Very helpful when debugging
  --install-packages [PKG [PKG ...]]
                        Packages that need to be installed
  --install-src-packages [SOURCE PKG [SOURCE PKG ...]]
                        Source Packages that need to be installed
  --src-build-dep       Install Build Dependency packages for requested source
                        packages
  --release release_name
                        Release target to install packages from
  --update              Generate Signature to update APT Database
  --upgrade             Generate Signature of packages to be upgraded
  --upgrade-type upgrade
                        Type of upgrade to do. Use one of upgrade, dist-
                        upgrade, dselect-ugprade
  --generate-changelog  Generate changelog of the version to be downloaded
  --apt-backend apt-get
                        APT backend to use. One of: apt, apt-get, python-apt
2017-01-22 / 19:05:24 ♒♒♒  ☺
```